# Sort photos in Php gallery by date

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, date, gallery

I'm trying to build a gallery for a friend, using PHP. Currently my script imports all the images from a "gallery" folder, and it displays them alphabetically, using automatically generated thumbnails and fancybox plugin. 
Is it posible to sort them by date? It doesn't matter if it's the date when they were taken or the date when they were last modified. The code I use is below. Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$path =  'gallery/'; 
$files = scandir('gallery/'); 
?>

<ul>
<?php foreach ($files as $file){
if ($file == '.' || $file == '..'){ 
    echo '';
} else {
?>

<li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $path . $file; ?>"><img src="scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $path . $file; ?>&h=194&w=224&zc=1&q=100" /></a></li>
<?php } }?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

this php function sorts your file by the last date it was modified. 
Don't forget to put in the ignored files array which files you want to be ignored.

```
function scan_dir($dir) {
    $ignored_files = array()
    $files = array();   
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
        if (in_array($file,$ignored_files) {
             $files[$file] = filemtime($dir.'/'.$file);
        }
    }

    arsort($files);
    $files = array_keys($files);

    if(is_null($files))
        return false;
    return $files;
}
```

You can refactor it a bit this was made really quicly. Hope this will work

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, the function doesn't seem to work, the photos are still sorted by name, and not by date.

Comment: have you checked that files[$file] is equal to the last modified date ? If you have that, you can sort them